# Ethernet adapter/router stopped generating/assigning global IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv6

My ISP provides dynamic IPv6 addresses which i use in conjunction with a DNS update script and a domain to access my computers from anywhere, but for some reason my ethernet network adapter or router started creating bogus IPs which are no longer accessible globally, though i did neither explicitly change the router's nor the computer's configuration.

Previously the IPs that were globally accessible had the adapter's MAC address encoded within, now i do no longer have any such IPs on the device. When running `ip addr` the correct IP used to be labeled `scope global noprefixroute dynamic`, which is still the correct one for one of my other computers which has no such problem (also running Arch Linux). Trying to connect to this address yields a permission denied error, though there should be no firewall at any point and it's not in the private block (`fe80::/10`).

I am quite at a loss as to what is going on here and what the source of the problem is.

Comment: First, it is hard to guess the problem without any addresses to look at. Does it only concern the local part (the last 64 bits) of the address? Then it could be that privacy extensions are activated (which should be considered a Good Thing™). Is it the prefix? Then what does the router say. Second, "permission denied" is not a network error. What did you try to connect to the host? Third, `fe80::` addresses are not a "private block", but the link-local range, they are not routable. Unique Local Addresses (ULA, `fc00::/7`) would be more like "private."

Comment: This is about the local part, prefix is fine. Tried SSH to connect.

Comment: HTTP requests also yield permission denied.

Comment: If you want to have a stable address, you can a) use DHCPv6, b) assign an address manually, or c) disable privacy extensions (setting the parameter `net.ipv6.conf.<iface>.use_tempaddr` to 0 using `sysctl`). AFAIK, newer Linux kernels can already generate stable privacy addresses, which would be another alternative.

Comment: "Permission denied" is still a strange error. Could you use `ssh -vv` to see where the error occurs?

Comment: The output of that seems not particularly helpful: `debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<XXX>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <XXX> [<XXX>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <XXX> port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host <XXX> port 22: Permission denied`